# This simple directive is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to learn Angular.

I have a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Qiu2SOjti2PVYhjRqO2O?p=preview

I'm trying to display a directive called 'simple' on the home page.

I'm not getting any console errors but the directive does not display.

```
(function(){
  angular.module('cxoJsApp').directive('simple', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'simpleController',
      controllerAs: 'simpleCtrl',
      scope: {},
      bindtoController: true,
      templateUrl: 'simpleDirective.html'
    };
  });
})();
```

Comment: Refer `<script src="simpleController.js"></script><script src="simpleDirective.js"></script>` on page after `app.js`, it should work.[Working plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mTAg7u5GPDEt961Vq7St?p=preview)

Comment: "I'm not getting any console errors"... check again, the plunker you posted *clearly* has `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HomeController' is not a function, got undefined`.

Comment: Hello! Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/loN714fULCcWrBhsN6C2?p=preview

You forgot to create the file `homeController.js` and to include all the files in your `index.html`:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="simpleController.js"></script> 
<script src="simpleDirective.js"></script> 
<script src="homeController.js"></script>
```

Nothing wrong with your directive! :)